# Texstudio 2.10.8 embedded viewer does not show up after Build&view F5

Tags: texstudio

All of a sudden my viewer would not pop up anymore whithout me changing anything in any options.

F7 view and ctrl+leftmouse work alright but when I re-build, the viewer wouldn't scroll to the current editing position.

I reinstalled but it seems that the configuration file remained.[B&V settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0KJQ.png)

Attached my settings, only focus is added in default viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

There was this `C_aus_IVT_RK` in the code below which provoked the following error:

**Missing $ inserted. ...gnorespaces C_aus_IVT_RK}}{67}{figure.12.7}
**

The compiler seemed to dislike the underscores.

Funny enough the pdf was compiled though.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{../TexS_FigVerz/C_aus_IVT_RK}
    \caption[C_aus_IVT_RK]{Captain Caption}
    \label{fig:C_aus_IVT_RK}
\end{figure}
```

Now, everything works alright.